# How do I solve 6b) and 6c) if my solution for 6a) is a consistent system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

$$\begin{cases}
2x_1-x_2= dx_1 \\ 
2x_1-x_2+x_3=dx_2 \\ 
-2x_1+2x_2+x_3=dx_3
\end{cases}
$$

a) Is it possible for the system to be inconsistent? Explain?

b) For what values of d will the system have infinitely many solutions?

c) Solve the system when it has infinitely many solutions?

For my solution in part a), 
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&0&0&0\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  0&0&1&0
\end{array}
\right] $$

Hence, it is a unique set of solutions i.e. the system cannot be inconsistent. So how is it possible to get infinitely many solutions in 6b) and 6c)?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Links to images are not accessible to screen readers. You can instead use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to type mathematics on this site – in particular the 'Systems of equations' part.

Comment: `For my solution in part a)` The rest of the question appears to center on this part, which you haven't posted. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and add at least some minimal context.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question accordingly, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: You should be able to tell that the system can’t be inconsistent by inspection: it’s homogeneous, so $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$ is always a solution.

Comment: How were you able to fully reduce the coefficient matrix without knowing what $d$ is? You might have divided by zero somewhere along the way, which would make the reduction invalid.

Comment: Ahh, I failed to consider that the case of zero, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Gaussian elimination method to solve a set of linear equations,

From the equations, you have given,

> \begin{cases}
> 2x_1-x_2= dx_1 \\ 
> 2x_1-x_2+x_3=dx_2 \\ 
> -2x_1+2x_2+x_3=dx_3
> \end{cases}

We can arrive at this augmented matrix,

\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  -d+2&-1&0&0\\
  2&-1-d&1&0\\
  -2&2&1-d&0
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}

Using row transformations,

\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  -2   &  2   & 1-d &0 \\
   2   & -1-d & 1   &0\\
  -d+2 & -1   & 0   &0\\
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{equation}
\downarrow
\end{equation}

\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  -2   &  2   & 1-d &0 \\
   0   &  1-d & 2-d   &0\\
   0   &  0   & (1-d)(2-d) -2(2-d)   &0\\
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}

For it to have infinite solutions,

\begin{equation}
(1-d)(2-d) -2(2-d) = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
d = 2, -1
\end{equation}

If $d$ takes the above value, then you will end up with a free variable ($x_3$)

\begin{equation}
x_2 = \frac{(d-2)x_3}{1-d}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x_1 = \frac{1}{2}(2x_2 + (1-d)x_3)
\end{equation}

Comment: May I know how you derived your last row to that? I can't seem to eliminate my first 2 columns of the last row to = 0...

Comment: Use $R_2 = R_1 + R_2$ ,$R_3 = (-d+2)R_1 + 2R_3$, then $R_3 = R_3 - 2R_2$ then it reduces to this form.

Comment: Got it, thank you for your help!